# Game camera won't render HDR emission on line renderer but scene view camera does

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so I am making a shooter, and I'm trying to add HDR emission to the line renderer from the gunpoint to the raycast point. Now it works great but my problem is that I applied a yellow intense HDR material on the line renderer and I can only see the bright emission in the scene view and not the game view. The HDR works fine, and when I apply the material on anything that isn't the line renderer, like say the floor, the HDR suddenly works in both scene and game view. Anyone have any advice? [Scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoNqg.png)

[Game view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfgfv.png)